# Using a for-loop to fill 20 picturebox number 'i' with image

Tags: c#

I implemented as follows and it works (I got the solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13436109/c-using-for-loop-to-fill-picturebox-number-i-with-image)), but I really wonder if I can do that without having to define an array. For 20 it's a hassle but can be done, but what if you have an hundred to do? Is there a more "aesthetic" way to do that?

```
public void afficheuneimagecombo()
    {
 for (int i = 0; i <= 20; i++)
       {
            Item imguse = new Item();
            pictureBoxs[i].Load(imguse.getImage());
            pictureBoxs[i].SizeMode = PictureBoxSizeMode.StretchImage
        }

      }

PictureBox[] pictureBoxs = new PictureBox[20];

public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            pictureBoxs[0] = pictureBox1;
            pictureBoxs[1] = pictureBox2;
            pictureBoxs[2] = pictureBox3;
            pictureBoxs[3] = pictureBox4;
            pictureBoxs[4] = pictureBox5;
              [...]
            pictureBoxs[20] = pictureBox20;


            afficheuneimagecombo()
        }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to ensure that the PictureBoxes are in the correct order in your List, then use this alternate approach such as this.  *They could be out of order if you ever copied and pasted the PictureBoxes to move them around on the form, or if you changed the names of the controls, etc...

Additionally, this will find all the PictureBoxes even if they reside in more than one container:

```
    List<PictureBox> pictureBoxes = new List<PictureBox>();

    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Control[] matches;
        for(int i = 1; i <= 100;i++)
        {
            matches = this.Controls.Find("pictureBox" + i.ToString(), true);
            if (matches.Length > 0 && matches[0] is PictureBox)
            {
                pictureBoxes.Add((PictureBox)matches[0]);
            }
        }
        Console.WriteLine(pictureBoxes.Count.ToString());
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you have a container for each of your `PictureBox` controls do the following:

Use a `List` control:

```
  List<PictureBox> boxes = new List<PictureBox>();
```

Search for your picture boxes:

```
  foreach (Control c in YourContainerName.Controls)
  {
    if (c is PictureBox)
    {
      boxes.Add(c);
    }
  }
```

Then in your method:

```
public void afficheuneimagecombo()
{
  foreach (PictureBox pb in boxes)
  {
    Item imguse = new Item();
    pb.Load(imguse.getImage());
    pb.SizeMode = PictureBoxSizeMode.StretchImage;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

**Casing**

Methods should be PascalCase:

```
public void afficheuneimagecombo(PictureBox pb)
```

should be:

```
public void AfficheUneImageCombo(PictureBox pb)
```

And you can probably remove "Une" from there too.

```
public void AfficheImageCombo(PictureBox pb)
```

Variable names should be camelCase:

```
Item imguse = new Item();
```

Should be:

```
Item imgUse = new Item();
```

**Naming**

Avoid using acronyms or shortened forms of words in variable, type and method names. By using the longer form, it is much clearer and easier for a maintenance programmer to understand.

```
Item imguse = new Item();
```

Should be:

```
Item imageUse = new Item();
```

**Var**

Prefer the `var` keyword when declaring local variables if the right hand side of the declaration makes the variable's type obvious.

```
Item imguse = new Item();
```

Should be:

```
var imguse = new Item();
```

Doing this makes it easier to change variable type later, and makes it more concise and easy to read for others.

Answer (score 0):

you can create a function called loadPictureboxes, selecting just the controls that matches the pattern:

```
    public void loadPictureboxes(Control container)
    {
        container.Controls.OfType<PictureBox>()
            .Where(c => Regex.IsMatch( c.Name,"PictureBox\\d") )
            .Select(c => c).ToList()
            .ForEach(afficheuneimagecombo);
    }
```

and modify the afficheuneimagecombo function as follows

```
    public void afficheuneimagecombo(PictureBox pb)
    {
        Item imguse = new Item();
        pb[i].Load(imguse.getImage());
        pb[i].SizeMode = PictureBoxSizeMode.StretchImage;
    }
```

and then in the constructor of the form:

```
        loadPictureboxes(NameOfTheContainer);
```